# getUserMedia dont upload after recording

Tags: javascript, getusermedia, web-mediarecorder, recordrtc

I have the following problem with getUserMedia, I try to upload the video after the recording is done but apparently it does not upload or does not respond, could someone help me? thanks.

When I click the "Stop And Upload" button I get null response .. I need to upload this file to webserver directly.

```
<div class="content">

<video playsinline poster="./poster.png" onclick="this.play();"></video>
<button id="btn-stop-recording" type="button" disabled>Stop And Upload</button>

<script src="./RecordRTC.js"></script>
//library URL (https://): webrtc-experiment.com/RecordRTC.js
<script>
var video = document.querySelector('video');

function captureCamera(callback) {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: true }).then(function(camera) {
        callback(camera);
    }).catch(function(error) {
        alert('Unable to capture your camera. Please check console logs.');
        console.error(error);
    });
}

function stopRecordingCallback() {
    video.src = video.srcObject = null;
    video.muted = false;
    video.volume = 1;
    //video.src = URL.createObjectURL(recorder.getBlob());
    video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(recorder.getBlob());
    document.write(video.src);
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('fname', 'test.webm');
    fd.append('data', video.srcObject);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: './true.php',
        data: fd,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false
    }).done(function(data) {
           console.log(data);
    });
}

var recorder; // globally accessible

document.getElementById('btn-start-recording').onclick = function() {
    this.disabled = true;
    captureCamera(function(camera) {
        video.muted = true;
        video.volume = 0;
        video.srcObject = camera;

        recorder = RecordRTC(camera, {
            type: 'video',
            mimeType: 'video/webm'
        });

        recorder.startRecording();

        // release camera on stopRecording
        recorder.camera = camera;

        document.getElementById('btn-stop-recording').disabled = false;
    });
};

document.getElementById('btn-stop-recording').onclick = function() {
    this.disabled = true;
    recorder.stopRecording(stopRecordingCallback);
};
</script>
<div>
```

File true.php >>>>

```
<?php
foreach(array('video') as $type) {
    if (isset($_FILES["${type}-blob"])) {

        echo 'uploads/';

        $fileName = $_POST["${type}-filename"];
        $uploadDirectory = 'uploads/'.$fileName;

        if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES["${type}-blob"]["tmp_name"], $uploadDirectory)) {
            echo(" problem moving uploaded file");
        }

        echo($fileName);
    }
}
?>
```

According to the console log, the file is sending to the server, but when the php file receives, it does not upload it to the server.

POST DATA FROM AJAX CALL:

```
POST /true.php HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:9090
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:74.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/74.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------39520532461108107029652486848
Content-Length: 644254
Origin: http://localhost:9090
Connection: close
Referer: http://localhost:9090/

-----------------------------39520532461108107029652486848
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fname"

test.webm
-----------------------------39520532461108107029652486848
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data"; filename="blob"
Content-Type: video/webm
```

Comment: `fd.append('data', video.srcObject);` should be `fd.append('data', recorder.getBlob())`.

Comment: Im getting null response with u change, dont redirect to true.php

Comment: There is no reason you get redirected, you are just doing an AJAX call, and remove that `document.write`, use `console.log` for logging. And try to log that `recorder.getBlob()` return value.

Comment: Hello, thanks for u response, indeed the file is being sent to the web server, now I am having another problem. When the php file receives, it does not upload it to the server, I will edit the post for more details of the true.php file, thanks your answer has worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This stuff is confusing, and with respect, you're confused. It's not `getUserMedia` doing the recording, it's `RecordRTC`.  The data you want to upload is the contents of the Blob given to you by `recorder.getBlob()`. And, that Blob contains binary data; you can't make much sense of its contents unless you use a package like [ebml](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ebml).

And, notice that `.getBlob()` returns a Promise, so you need `.then()` to know when your Blob is ready.

But, you are close.  You want to upload the Blob. A few changes and you're ready to go.

```
function stopRecordingCallback() {
    recorder.getBlob()
    /* getBlob completes normally */
    .then (function(blob) {
        const fd = new FormData()
        fd.append('fname', 'test.webm')
        fd.append('data', blob)
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: './true.php',
            data: fd,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false
        })
        .done(function(data) {
           console.log(data)
    })
    /* getBlob's promise rejected */
    .catch(console.err)
}
```

I haven't debugged this, but it is close to things I've done.

It looks like you might be trying to set up your `<video>` element to preview the recorded video. If that's true, I suggest you get the upload working, then get the preview working.

**Pro tip** Your code for this WebRTC media stuff will be shorter and much easier to read if you start using `async` / `await` in place of `.then()` and callbacks. Figuring out  `async` / `await`  is one of the best investments of time you can make.

Comment: Hi, thanks for u response but I was looking at the console log, and if I was sending it, the problem is when receiving in the php, you can check the post again, I have edited it for a better understanding.